# How do I get this class name via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Attempting to create an accordion, but I can't figure out to check if the wrapper has the active class.

My jQuery:

```
$('.faq_wrap span.plus').on(touchClick, function (e) {
    var topEl = $(this).closest('.faq_wrap');
    if (topEl.hasClass('active')) {
        topEl.removeClass('active');
        topEl.find('.answer').slideUp('fast');
        return false;
    }
    topEl.each(function (index, el) {
        topEl.removeClass('active');
        topEl.find('.answer').slideUp('fast');
    });
    topEl.find('.answer').slideDown('fast');
    topEl.addClass('active');
    console.log(topEl);
});
```

Here's the output from `console.log`:

[image]

I'm trying to check whether `.faq_wrap.active` already exists. If it does, slide the accordion up before sliding the new one down. As of right now, this check is ignored and I can open as many accordions at once as I want. Thoughts?

Comment: touchClick is a variable or a string ?

Comment: What does your HTML look like?  You're logging `topEl.children`, but checking `topEl.hasClass`.  What happens if you `console.log(topEl);`?

Comment: If there can only ever be one `.active` piece, why not simply do `if ($('.faq_wrap.active')) { ... rest of code`? Wondering why you only check the *closest* `.faq_wrap` too.

Comment: @YuliamChandra touchClick is just a click variable I have set since I'm working with mobile devices.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Sorry about that, `.children` was leftover from earlier testing.

Comment: @Tyblitz That just made sense to me. I'm new to jQuery/JavaScript. If you have a better method I'd love to hear it!

Comment: Can you have more that one element with `.active`?

Comment: @Tyblitz Wouldn't you need to do `if ($('.faq_wrap.active').length)`? jQuery will return an object with no matched elements, but the object will have the jQuery content. I think that would evaluate to _"truthy"_ as opposed to the `.length` property which could be false if `0` matched elements were found.

Comment: @War10ck Good point, I was thinking too much vanilla JS :)

Comment: Why not just use the [jQuery UI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/)

```
topEl.get(0).className
```

Comment: Can that be changed to getting the full div? Just so I can check if it has class active or not.

Comment: Sure, just use `topEl.get(0)`

Comment: okay, another question (sorry im dumb):
why do i get `undefined is not a function` when i swap the following in, on my 2nd line:
`var topEl = $(this).closest('.faq_wrap').get(0);`

Comment: Because then the element is no longer a jQuery object but a plain JavaScript DOM object, and on this you can't call methods like `.hasClass`or `.each`.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple collapsible/ expandable sections in your HTML, from which only one is ever going to be active (expanded). You use `.closest()` but if there's only one you could just as well use the direct class selector `.faq_wrap.active` (it will return either 0 or 1 element, depending on whether the user has already clicked). There's also no point in doing `topEl.each` because `.closest()` will return only the closest node (here, the parent). So the following should be better ( & more concise)

```
$('.faq_wrap span.plus').on(touchClick, function (e) {
    var topEl = $(this).closest('.faq_wrap'),
        activeEl = $('.faq_wrap.active');

    if (activeEl.length) { // implied: if it's bigger than 0
        activeEl.removeClass('active');
        activeEl.find('.answer').slideUp('fast');
    }
    topEl.find('.answer').slideDown('fast');
    topEl.addClass('active');
});
```

NB: Just wondering, why did you use the `return false;` statement?